# How to Check Conditions with Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am updating this question to better clarify what am looking for...so I am passing an array to a function which is supposed to update a cart...I have two variables, $isbn and $formatQuantiy...
Here is my problem before updating the database I need to check a few condition
1. check if isbn exists, if it does just update $formatQuantiy, if it does not create a column with isbn as primary key
2. $formatQuantity could be softcover,hardcover, or ebook...I need to update the quantity of the right column so if format is softcover I need to add 1 to the current value of column softcover purchase..
Here is my code...
P.s I know how to do everything else but I don't know how to check the condition with MySQL

```
<?php
  function insertBook($db,$selection){
    $isbn;
    $format;


   foreach ($selection as $key => $value) {
       $isbn=$key;
       $format=$value;
       $change= explode(":", $format) ;
       $format=$change['0'];


   }


$query = "INSERT INTO cart (isbn, hardcover_purchased, softcover_purchased, ebook_purchased)
          VALUES (':isbn', ':format', 0, 0)";

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$success = $statement->execute();
$statement->bindValue(':isbn', $isbn);
$statement->bindValue(':format', $format);
$statement->closeCursor();
if ($success) {
  echo "section inserted using query insertNewSection_checkSuccess";
}
else{
  echo "Unable to insert new section using query insertNewSection_checkSuccess";
}
}

 ?>
```

Comment: You're using placeholders, which is great, but they should be put in as-is, without quotes. If necessary quotes will be added by the driver. I'm also not sure why you call `closeCursor()` instead of `execute()`.

Comment: @tadman Actually, he prepares, executes and after execution binding the values, then for some reason closing the cursor.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. This code is so confused I'm not sure how it could ever work. Will, you should find a better reference. [The main documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) is a good place to start.